# Latex custom counters

Tags: macros, counters, greek

I have been studying the way that custom enumeration labels work
From source2e.pdf I get:

```
\def\alph#1{\expandafter\@alph\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@alph#1{
     \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or j\or
        k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or s\or t\or u\or 
        v\or w\orx\ory\or z\else\@ctrerr\fi}
```

I have also been using the working example from [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277117/how-to-create-a-list-with-numbering-greek-letters/277157)

```
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\greekalpha}[1]{\c@greekalpha{#1}}
    \newcommand{\c@greekalpha}[1]{{
        \ifcase\number\value{#1} \or α \or β \or γ \or δ \or\fi}}
\makeatother
```

So I tried my own version of greek alphabet in an almost gargo cult manner to see what happens:

```
\makeatletter
    \def\greekc#1{\expandafter\@greekc\csname c@#1 \endcsname}
    \def\@greekc#1{\ifcase #1 \or α\or β\or γ\or δ\else\@ctreerr \fi}
\makeatother
```

Unfortunately it produces an error: 'Missing number, treated as zero'
in the following example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Uppercase=Regular,Lowercase=Regular,]        {Bookman Old Style}
\setmainfont{Bookman Old Style}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\begin{document}
\newcounter{greekctr}\stepcounter{greekctr}\stepcounter{greekctr}

\makeatletter
    \def\greekc#1{\expandafter\@greekc\csname c@#1 \endcsname}
    \def\@greekc#1{\ifcase #1 \or α\or β\or γ\or δ\else\@ctreerr \fi}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\greekalpha}[1]{\c@greekalpha{#1}}
    \newcommand{\c@greekalpha}[1]{%
        {%
            \ifcase\number\value{#1} \or α \or β \or γ \or δ \or\fi
        }%
    }
\makeatother
\noindent
\begin{itemize}
    \item Value of counter: \thegreekctr
    \item Alph counter :\alph{greekctr}
    \item greekalpha: \greekalpha{greekctr}
    \item greekc: \greekc{greekctr}
\end{itemize}

Working use in enumerate environment:
\AddEnumerateCounter*{\greekalpha}{\c@greekalpha}{γ}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\greekalpha*]   
    \item First
    \item Second 
    \item Third
    \item Fourth
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Could please somebody explain why my example does not work and also why the other two examples do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You was getting an error because of an extra space inside `\csname...\endcsname`...

When you do `\csname cs\endcsname` you define a control sequence `\cs` because TeX ignores spaces after control sequence names. But when you do `\csname cs \endcsname`, the space *after* `cs` is considered and the control sequence you create is actually `\cs␣` (`␣` denotes a space).

---

*Fun (?) fact:* A lot of commands use a space after the name of the control sequence to store a "secret" version of the command. For example, if you create a document and put `\show\cite` in it, you'll see:

```
> \cite=macro:
->\protect \cite  .
```

then you'll ask: *but then I cannot see the definition of `\cite`?* Yes, you can! Notice that there is a space after the `\cite` in the second line. To see the `\cite␣` macro you do:

```
\expandafter\show\csname cite \endcsname
```

with a space after `cite` :)

---

Also, there was an extra space after `α`, `β`, `γ`, and `δ` in `\c@greekalpha`. I removed them for you. This space was not causing an error but it would appear when printed in the pdf.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Uppercase=Regular,Lowercase=Regular,]        {Bookman Old Style}
\setmainfont{Bookman Old Style}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{greekctr}\stepcounter{greekctr}\stepcounter{greekctr}

% \tracingonline=1
% \tracingmacros=1

\makeatletter%                                    V no space here!
    \def\greekc#1{\expandafter\@greekc\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \def\@greekc#1{\ifcase #1 \or α\or β\or γ\or δ\else\@ctreerr \fi}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\greekalpha}[1]{\c@greekalpha{#1}}
    \newcommand{\c@greekalpha}[1]{%
        {%                                v    v    v    v And no spaces here
            \ifcase\number\value{#1} \or α\or β\or γ\or δ\or\fi
        }%
    }
\makeatother
\noindent

\begin{itemize}
    \item Value of counter: \thegreekctr
    \item Alph counter :\alph{greekctr}
    \item greekalpha: \greekalpha{greekctr}
    \item greekc: \greekc{greekctr}
\end{itemize}

Working use in enumerate environment:
\AddEnumerateCounter*{\greekalpha}{\c@greekalpha}{γ}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\greekalpha*]
    \item First
    \item Second
    \item Third
    \item Fourth
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! You have no idea of the hours spent on this.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with `\csname c@#1 \endcsname`. There is a space after `#1`, so for example if `#1` is `section` this results in `\c@section` with a final space in the name of the command sequence. This is not defined, so TeX finds an undefined control sequence instead of a number which leads to the error.
To fix this you have to delete the space before `\endcsname`. The space after `\csname` is different. It is not included in the name of the command sequence because spaces after a command sequence like `\csname` are gobbled by TeX after functioning as a terminator of the name of the command sequence. It is even necessary, because otherwise `\csnamec@` would be interpreted as one (undefined) command sequence.

Comment: Maybe you should rewrite that bit about "the space after `\csname`". This space is not only not a problem but mandatory. Else you try to use `\csnamec@` which is not a defined control sequence.